# How to create test schema with stored procedures in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I have a Rails 6 webapp with some stored procedures I would like to test. How do I do that, ie where should I put those procedures so they'd be recreated upon db setup? Because `db:schema:dump` isnt awfully friendly towards them (procedures), it does not include them.

Comment: We've solved this problem by adding folders under db for views, functions and procedures.  We add the SQL create commands, one file per object.

Then we extended the db migration task to then call a task to drop and create the database objects using the scripts.

Comment: Switch to SQL schema dumps instead. Most non-trivial apps usually eventually hit a point where you want to use DB specific features which the Ruby schema dumper doesn't support. https://blog.appsignal.com/2020/01/15/the-pros-and-cons-of-using-structure-sql-in-your-ruby-on-rails-application.html